# Camunda clean up for completed process instance and variables

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am using Camunda for workflow management. I found that over period of time, Camunda table(variable and process instance) grows and creates performance issues on new process.

Initially, It was due to history level, I managed to clean history and set level zero so no new history will be persisted.

I see there are millions of records in *act_ru_variable* table which is degrading performance for running processes.

I do not need Camunda table related variable or process instance data for completed/terminated process anymore.

Can anyone suggest some configuration/approach/scripts to clean Camunda entries for completed/terminated process instance?

Please comment if more detail required.

Comment: `act_ru_variable` only stores variables of active/running processes. Variables are removed from this table when the process instance ends.

Comment: Thanks @Ivar. My Bad. After your comment, I checked my setup. I found few scenarios are missed to be terminated so it was increasing table count.